# Update a specific sheet name in all the excels inside a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

In a folder, I have 50 excel files with multiple sheets in each file. I have to update the name of the sheet in these files where ever the sheet_name contains "XYZ".

So for each file, if the sheet_name has "XYZ", change that sheet_name to "ABC". I tried looping through the files using the following code but could not write code to change sheet names :

```
filelist=[]
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if (file.endswith('.xlsx') or file.endswith('.xls') or file.endswith('.XLS')):
            filelist.append(os.path.join(path, file))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify like that to list files:

```
import os
mypath = r'C:\your\files\path'
filenames = [x for x in os.listdir(mypath) if x.endswith('.xls') or x.endswith('.xlsx') or x.endswith('.XLS')]
for filename in filenames:
    a = filename.replace('XYZ','ABC')
    os.rename(mypath+"/"+filename,mypath+"/"+a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use openpyxl and glob

```
import glob
from openpyxl import load_workbook
paths = glob.glob("directory*xls*") + glob.glob("directory*XLS*")
for path in paths:
    wb = load_workbook(path)
    for sheetname in wb.sheetnames:
        ws = wb[sheetname]
        if "XYZ" in ws.title:
            ws.title = "ABC"
    wb.save(path)
```